# How to correctly step through tests on different pages in Protractor e2e test?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

We want to use protractor to visit a page, run some tests, and then go to another page for more tests. But the later navigation appears to interfere the tests on the previous page.

Here is the structure:

```
describe('When user is an admin', function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl + 'login');
    loginAs(roles.admin);
    wait();

    describe('After log in', function () {

        it('should redirect to the home page', function () {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + 'home');
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should contain a "Locations" tab', function () {
            var tabLocations = element(by.id('tabLocations'));
            expect(tabLocations.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should contain a link to location list', function () {
            var linkLocation = element(by.linkText('Manage Locations'));
            expect(linkLocation.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        });

    });
});
```

Pasted above is the tests on the first page.

Then we want to run the tests on another page: (full coded pasted below)

```
describe('When user is an admin', function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl + 'login');
    loginAs(roles.admin);
    wait();

    describe('After log in', function () {

        it('should redirect to the home page', function () {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + 'home');
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should contain a "Locations" tab', function () {
            var tabLocations = element(by.id('tabLocations'));
            expect(tabLocations.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should contain a link to location list', function () {
            var linkLocation = element(by.linkText('Manage Locations'));
            expect(linkLocation.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        });

    });



    describe('at location manage page', function () {
        var listPage = new ListPage();
        listPage.visit('Manage Locations');
        wait();
        it('should be at the location list page', function () {
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + 'locations/list');
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });
});
```

It appears the navigation in my second `describe` runs before the execution of `it` statements in the first `describe`, therefore my tests on the first page failed.

---

I've tried placing the second `describe` ("at location manage page") inside the first `describe` ("After log in"), but still got the same problem.

So my question is, what is the correct way to arrange the tests in protractor, so as the navigation in later tests will be held until the previous tests are completed?

Answer (score 4):

Do not put code inside a describe. Put it inside a `beforeAll(function(){})` (jasmine 2) or a `beforeEach(function() {})`

That should fix your problem.